# android - notifications hide when I look the screen

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

it's very weird and it happens just for my app. When I turn off my phone screen and turn it on again, it clears all of my notification despite it doesn't happens for other apps on my phone.

this is my code:

```
Intent resultIntent = resultIntent = new Intent(mContext, intentClass);
resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
resultIntent.putExtra("onvan", title);
resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);
resultIntent.putExtra("link", link);
resultIntent.putExtra("linktype", linktype);
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

TaskStackBuilder TSB = TaskStackBuilder.create(mContext);
TSB.addParentStack(intentClass);
TSB.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        TSB.getPendingIntent(
                new Random().nextInt(),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );

mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
mBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

I don't want to clear the notification when the screen turns off, I want it to clear when use manually clears it

what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You're using

```
setAutoCancel(true)
```

As per documentation

> setAutoCancel(boolean autoCancel)
>
> Make this notification automatically
>   dismissed when the user touches it.

I would try setting auto cancel to false.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the screen being on or off. This only dismisses the notif is user clicks on it